# How do I find nodes that are connected with >1 path and return their connecting nodes?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am starting with Neo4j and cypher and tried to play around with the default movie Graph.

I want to find all actors that worked with Tom Hanks in more than one movie and list the movies they worked in together.

Finding the actors and amount of movies works

```
MATCH p=(a {name:"Tom Hanks"})-[r*2]-(b)
WITH count(p) AS commonMovies, a, b
WHERE commonMovies > 1
RETURN DISTINCT commonMovies, b.name
Order By commonMovies DESC;
```

Output:

3 | Meg Ryan

2 | Gary Sinise

etc.

Finding the movies they worked in together works for all actors that worked with Tom Hanks:

```
MATCH p=(a {name:"Tom Hanks"})-[r*2]-(b)
RETURN b.name, extract(n in nodes(p)[1..-1] | n.title);
```

Output:

Tom Hanks       | That thing you do

Liv Tyler       | That thing you do

Charlize Theron | That thing you do

Nora Ephron     | Zou've got mail

What I would like to have is something like:

Actor | [array of movies]

I think the problem is that I aggregate with count(p) but afterwards I cannot extract the nodes from each path. That's at least what appears to be the problem for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current query may return you Tom Hanks himself, this one do the job :

```
MATCH (n:Person {name:'Tom Hanks'})-->(m:Movie)<--(other)
WITH other.name as coActor, collect(m.title) as movies
WHERE size(movies) > 1
RETURN coActor, movies
```